# Label content is not displayed properly on Marker

Tags: css, google-maps

I have following code to display a label on marker. This is working but numbers greater that 10 are cropped to single digits( if 10 it shows 1...etc). How to change font size or label width? Or is there any other solution to display full text?

```
var label = (x+1).toString() 
var marker = new Array();
      var image = 'images/image.png';
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: latlng, 
        title: "Address",
        radius: int_radius ,
        draggable: false,
        label: {
    text: label,
    color: 'white'


  },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        icon: image,
        labelClass: "labels",
        customInfo: "<p><strong>Store Name</strong></p>"+storename[x]+"<p><strong>Address</strong></p>"+address[x]+"<p><strong>Phone</strong></p>"+phone[x]
      });
```

When apply font-size, the "-" character gives an error.Please help.

Comment: Anyone ready for the challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

Marker-labels currently are limited to 1 visible character.

You may create a custom overlay(e.g. via http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/reference.html )

Another option: dynamic images (e.g. https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons , but it's deprecated)